# Delete attributes and classes

Tags: javascript

In my script I am doing a notification management, where each new notification is highlighted with:

```
@if(Auth::user()->notification_count() >= 1)
    <span class="badge badge-pill bg-red" id="notify">
        {{ Auth::user()->notification_count() }}
    </span>
@endif
```

In the Javascript code, by clicking, it executes the query to read all the notifications and removes the class:

```js
success:function(res) {
    if(res.bool==true) {
        $("#notify").removeClass('badge badge-pill bg-red');
    }
}
```

It works, but unfortunately the number of notifications remains, here is an example.

[Image Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TRLyN.png)

Comment: What libraries/frameworks are you using? It'd be good to tag those as well

Comment: in success, you have just removed class, nothing for notification_count(). set notification_count() -1 or equals to zero

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are only removing the class, thus the notification still appears but with no styling. You can either remove it or set it do `display:none`. However, I suggest you hide it, since if you remove it you will have to create the bubble again.

Hide the notification:

```
success: function(res) {
  if(res.bool == true){
    $("#notify").css("display","none");
  }
}
```

Remove the notification:

```
success: function(res) {
  if(res.bool == true){
    $("#notify").parentElement.removeChild($("#notify"));
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you very much, it works. I'm not very experienced, I was wondering if this is a correct syntax or a "loophole"? I'm just asking because I'm trying to do a clean job.

Comment: No, this is regular syntax. There is no "trick" or "loophole" involved in doing it.